# Django : presenting a form very different from the model and with multiple field values in a Django-ish way?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently doing a firewall management application for Django, here's the (simplified) model :

```
class Port(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    application = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)

class Rule(models.Model):
    port = models.ForeignKey(Port)
    ip_source = models.IPAddressField()
    ip_mask = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(32)])
    machine = models.ForeignKey("vmm.machine")
```

What I would like to do, however, is to display to the user a form for entering rules, but with a very different organization than the model :

## Port 80

O Not open

O Everywhere

O Specific addresses :

--------- delete field

--------- delete field

`+` add address field

## Port 443

... etc

Where `Not open` means that there is no rule for the given port, `Everywhere` means that there is only ONE rule (0.0.0.0/0) for the given port, and with `specific addresses`, you can add as many addresses as you want (I did this with JQuery), which will make as many rules.

Now I did a version completely "handmade", meaning that I create the forms entirely in my templates, set input names with a  prefix, and parse all the POSTed stuff in my view (which is quite painful, and means that there's no point in using a web framework).

I also have a class which aggregates the rules together to easily pre-fill the forms with the informations "not open, everywhere, ...". I'm passing a list of those to the template, therefore it acts as an interface between my model and my "handmade" form :

```
class MachinePort(object):
    def __init__(self, machine, port):
        self.machine = machine
        self.port = port

    @property
    def fully_open(self):
        for rule in self.port.rule_set.filter(machine=self.machine):
            if ipaddr.IPv4Network("%s/%s" % (rule.ip_source, rule.ip_mask)) == ipaddr.IPv4Network("0.0.0.0/0"):
                return True
        else :
            return False

    @property
    def partly_open(self):
        return bool(self.port.rule_set.filter(machine=self.machine)) and not self.fully_open

    @property
    def not_open(self):
        return not self.partly_open and not self.fully_open
```

But all this is rather ugly ! Do anyone of you know if there is a classy way to do this ? In particular with the form... I don't know how to have a form that can have an undefined number of fields, neither how to transform these fields into `Rule` objects (because all the rule fields would have to be gathered from the form), neither how to save multiple objects... Well I could try to hack into the Form class, but seems like too much work for such a special case. Is there any nice feature I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got it running by making the models closer to what I wanted to present to the user. But related to the topic of the question :

**1)** Nested forms/formsets are not a built-in Django feature, are a pain to implement by yourself, and are actually not needed... Rather, one should use forms' and formsets' prefixes.

**2)** Trying to work with forms not based on the models, process the data, then reinject it in the models, is much much more code than modifying the models a little bit to have nice model-based forms.
So what I did is I modified the models like that :

```
class PortConfig(Serializable):
    port = models.ForeignKey(Port, editable=False)
    machine = models.ForeignKey("vmm.machine", editable=False)
    is_open = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="not_open", choices=is_open_choices)

class Rule(Serializable):
    ip_source = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    port_config = models.ForeignKey(PortConfig)
```

Then I simply used a "model formset" for `PortConfig`, and "model inline formset" for `Rule`, with a `PortConfig` as foreign key, and it went perfectly

**3)** I used this great JS library http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/ to put the "add field" and "delete field" links ... you almost have nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create usual Forms objects by subclassing `Form` and adding fields in constructor, as in:

```
self.base_fields[field_name] = field_instance
```

As for the `Rule`, You can create a custom `Field` that will `validate()` itself according to Your rules and add it to Your custom form as above.

So Yes, it must be handmande (AFAIK), but it's not so much code.